# how to change the style of the web page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to add the style or update the style of the index.html in web page. Default it is showing as below. I want to change the position to relative. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the web page is open by webview embedded in flutter, there's 2 way:

1. you can provide another html with specific style in it like  `mobile_index.html` for showing in flutter purpose.
2. you can run js script via webview to update the style, after webview loaded.